# ModelAndView("/authenticationError"); not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

after getting request from ajax to controller i am not able to move to next page through  ModelAndView("/authenticationError.jsp");
 controller code

@RequestMapping(value = "/ProcessReject,method = RequestMethod.POST" )

```
public  ModelAndView Reject(@RequestParam(value = "StatusComments") String StatusComments,
        @RequestParam(value = "ruleIndex") String ruleIndex,
        @RequestParam(value = "country") String country,
        HttpSession session) throws Exception {
 ModelAndView mav ;
 System.out.println("StatusComments   "+ StatusComments);
 System.out.println("ruleIndex  "+ ruleIndex);
 System.out.println("country  "+ country);
 String quicklookid = (String) session.getAttribute("quicklookid");

 //rejectRuleBusinessLogic.reject(ruleIndex, country, quicklookid, StatusComments);

 mav =  new ModelAndView("/authenticationError.jsp");
 return  mav;
```

Ajax code

```
function showRejectStatusMsg(value1, value2)
{

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    url: "ProcessViewRule.ncr",
                    data:"ruleIndex=" +value1 +"&country="+value2,

              success: function(response) { 
                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error in response...' + e);
                }


                });
```

jsp code -

```
<a href="javascript:showRejectStatusMsg(<c:out value='${List.ruleindex}'/>, '<c:out value="${List.country}"/>')" id="rejectLink" class="navlink" >Reject</a>))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong..You need  to write `.jsp` and can set the view as

```
 mav.setViewName("list");
```

Basically

```
 new ModelAndView("welcomePage", "WelcomeMessage", message);
```

is shorthand for

```
ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
mav.setViewName("welcomePage");
mav.addObject("WelcomeMessage", message);
```